# Why doesn't the buttons take the full size of parent here?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I want to make the Repos and stars buttons take the whole height of parent like the github icon. The below code is not working . I also tried giving `height:100%` for the flatButtonStyle but the whole `Paper` component's height increases to take the whole page . How to fix this  ?

```
return <>
          <Grid container>
                <Paper>
                    <Button style={flatButtonStyle}><GithubSVG /></Button>
                    <Tooltip title="Visit github.com/nateshmbhat">
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/nateshmbhat" style={{ padding: '10px' }}>nateshmbhat</a>
                    </Tooltip>
                    <Button style={flatButtonStyle}><i className="fa fa-archive"></i> repos</Button>
                    <Button style={flatButtonStyle}><i className="fa fa-star"></i> Stars</Button>
                </Paper>
          </Grid>
        </>
```

Comment: Do you have padding or margin for any of those elements. css for fa?

Comment: it looks like `Paper` has some `padding` or `margin` - try `<Paper style={margin:0, padding:0}>`, just to test - if that's fixes the layout you should override its style in css

Comment: tried setting margin and padding of Paper to 0 , didn't work

Comment: @varoons No i don't have css

Comment: check for `margin` on the buttons

Comment: @ic3b3rg still doesn't work .

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the dom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub button is taking up the whole height of the `paper` container because the GitHub SVG gives it the greatest height and the `paper` container conforms to its content since it does not possess a fixed height.

In order to set an equal height for all buttons you will either need to set a fixed `height` on the `paper` container and set each of the buttons' `min-height` to `100%` or set a fixed `height` on the buttons with a value matching that of the GitHub button as it possesses the greatest `height`.